# Convert DataTable to nested json in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, json.net

I want to convert datatable into nested json but get following error:

> "An item with the same key has already been added."

Data

```
CstCmpCode       Main_Group      Sub_Group    ClosBal
 AH01            Neck Wraps        AFGHANI      7
```

Now I want JSON result something like:

```
{
  "CstCmpCode": "AH01",
  "Main_Group": "Neck Wraps",
  "sub_group": [
    {
      "Sub_Group": "AFGHANI",
      "ClosBal": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

I used the following code:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TallyWeb"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select CstCmpCode, Loaded_date, Main_Group, Sub_Group, ClosBal from TlyStkSumm where CstCmpCode = @CstCmpCode";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CstCmpCode", CstCmpCode);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();

var main = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
{
    string Main_Group = rs["Main_Group"].ToString();
    Dictionary<string, string> sub;
    if (!main.TryGetValue(Main_Group, out sub))
    {
        sub = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        main.Add(Main_Group, sub);
    }

    sub.Add(rs["Sub_Group"].ToString(), (string)rs["ClosBal"]);
}

RootObject root = new RootObject { main = main };


public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("main")]
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> main { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what is the problem

Comment: it is showing message as "An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: and i want convert my datatable into Nested Json string so, i can serialize the json string as above json output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a DataTable to nested JSON output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752368/converting-a-datatable-to-nested-json-output)

Comment: pls. suggest me what i am going wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code here:

```
string Main_Group = rs["Main_Group"].ToString();
Dictionary<string, string> sub;
if (!main.TryGetValue(Main_Group, out sub))
{
    sub = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    main.Add(Main_Group, sub);
}

sub.Add(rs["Sub_Group"].ToString(), (string)rs["ClosBal"]);
             ^^^^^^^
```

I assume the problem is here - you add to the `sub` dictionary the `rs["Sub_Group"]` without checking if it exists. So if you have the same `Sum_Group` twice for that `Main_group` value it will throw the exception you get.

Comment: @YogeshSharma - did this help you solve your problem?

Comment: yes since last two days i facing this problem and this is new for me ...

Comment: @YogeshSharma - check your data. You are adding a sub_group that already exists. You should use `TryGetValue` or `ContainsKey` for it.

Comment: no but it is showing error as "Error converting value \"AFGHANI\" to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebService+SubGroup]\u0027. Path \u0027[0].Sub_Group\u0027, line 1, position 69."

Comment: @Yogesh - Not sure what you are doing but it isn't related to the previous problem of key already exists

Comment: i have  create some class and deserialize directly

Comment: As far as this question goes the above solves it. I shouldn't try and solve this new one in the comments - if after searching online (there are many serialization questions asked) you can't solve it then you can post another question

Comment: i don't know what i am doing but, as i know if i want to get above json format output then it will ceate some class for deserialization.

Comment: but, i am confused how to deserialize the json string.

Comment: Ya of course. But again - there are at least 3-5 c# json questions a day -  sure that a good search will help you find the answer

Comment: check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988782/problems-in-deserializing-json-with-nested-arrays-in-c-sharp

Comment: Please consider marking this question as solved and upvoting