# Problems in Deserializing JSON with nested arrays in C#

Tags: c#, json

> "Error converting value \"\u0004 Primary\" to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebService+SubGroup]\u0027. Path \u0027[0].Sub_Group\u0027, line 1, position 68."

Data

```
CstCmpCode       Main_Group      Sub_Group    ClosBal
 AH01            Neck Wraps        AFGHANI      7
```

Now I want JSON result something like:

```
 {
  "CstCmpCode": "AH01",
  "Main_Group": "Neck Wraps",
  "sub_group": [
    {
      "Sub_Group": "AFGHANI",
      "ClosBal": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

I used the following code:

```
  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TallyWeb"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select CstCmpCode, Main_Group, Sub_Group, ClosBal from TlyStkSumm where CstCmpCode = @CstCmpCode";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CstCmpCode", CstCmpCode);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
        foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }

      var json = serializer.Serialize(rows);

      var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });
```

Class as below :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string CstCmpCode { get; set; }
    public string Main_Group { get; set; }
    public List<SubGroup> sub_group { get; set; }
}

 public class SubGroup
{
    public string Sub_Group { get; set; }
    public int ClosBal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] for your problem that we could copy into a console app and run?  Also, if you add `Console.WriteLine(json);` after `var json = serializer.Serialize(rows);` then what is the exact JSON shown?

Comment: Also, what is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the **complete** message, exception type, traceback, and inner exception (if any)?

Comment: json string as json="[{\"CstCmpCode\":\"AH02\",\"Main_Group\":\"NA\",\"Sub_Group\":\"\\u0004 Primary\",\"ClosBal\":7269},{\"CstCmpCode\":\"AH02\",\"Main_Group\":\"NA\",\"Sub_Group\":\"\\u0004 Primary\",\"ClosBal\":3532}]"

Comment: Is that really what you got when you did `Console.WriteLine(j‌​son);`?  Because it looks like all the double quotes have been escaped which does not happen when the string is output to the console.

Comment: i think i am getting wrong json string it is showing plain but i need to nested json string after then i can Deserialize correctly.